# django conditional max for each with foreign key

Tags: django, foreach, aggregate, django-queryset

consider these models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForigenKey(Author)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I want to query **all** the Authors, with the latest(e.g `Max('created_at')` ) book of them in the same row, but only when the book is `active=True`.
I need to **whole** related book object - not just the max date.
If there is no such a book - all are active=False, or they simply do not exist - the query should output `NULL` where needed instead of the a book .

I've tried to write something like this:

```
Author.objects.annotate(max_book_date=Max('book'))
```

which does work, but it's missing additional fields on the book, and I'm not sure how it works in case of null (i.e no books), and the `active=True` condition is not there..

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should define a related_name param in the author fk field on the Book model:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='libro')
```

Then, you should be able to do something like:

```
Author.objects.filter(libro__active=True).annotate(max_book_date=Max('libro__created_at')).all()
```

Comment: This is not enough for me, I need the related book object( its name and more details) not just the max date. BTW I don't think the call to .all() at the end helps in something